# How to create data sequence with excel formula?

Tags: excel

what i need is formula to create data in column B based on column A
if data in column A = 1 then column B is 1, if A=2 B still 1
If data in A=1 again B is 2

```
A       B
1       1
2       1
3       1
1       2
2       2
1       3
1       4
2       4
```

what formula to create value in column B

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try the following formula in column B row 3, assuming that there are no headers in A and B:

```
=IF(A2>A1, B1, B1+1)
```

And drag it down (or copy/paste it). But you will have to put the first number in the first cell B1.

```
  |  A       B
--+--------------
1 |  1       1     => 1
2 |  2       1     => =IF(A2>A1, B1, B1+1)
3 |  3       1     => =IF(A3>A2, B2, B2+1)
4 |  1       2     .
5 |  2       2     .
6 |  1       3     .
7 |  1       4
8 |  2       4
```

Comment: @ian You're welcome! Feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/192545) :)